# Man Ray Techniques

Tags: reverse-engineering, photo-critique, image-analysis

The surrealist photographer(Man Ray) uses  techniques I'm unfamiliar with (photogram) And was wondering about the techniques used in this image,

I've been read some good articles including this good one: https://www.theartstory.org/artist-ray-man.htm

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[I really suspect I am doing your homework for you here.]

No camera techniques were used: this is a [*photogram*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogram), where paper is exposed to light directly with no camera, using a point light source far from the paper (quite likely an enlarger stopped right down with no film in the holder).  Man Ray was, or at least may have been, the inventor of photograms & made a fairly large number of them.  In this case there are at least, I think, three exposures:

- the dark diagonal stripe & dark area on the left is the negative space left by two darkroom trays sitting on top of the paper next to each other.
- there are patterns left by two hands;
- two people kissing have then put their heads over the paper (or possibly one person twice in each direction).

Just [searching](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=man+ray+the+kiss&t=ffab&ia=web) for it would have found all this information: Man Ray is quite well-known.

Comment: Regarding your comment about homework, this isn't OP's first question that reeks of homework, given [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/108256/what-techniques-and-concepts-did-joachim-froese-use-in-this-black-and-white-phot) and [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/108375/what-techniques-and-concepts-did-jan-groover-use-in-this-photo) question

Comment: @timvrhn: yes, I know.  Is there a policy (on this SE) that such questions should not be answered?  Probably there should be, as if it *is* a homework question then it's clearly cheating.

Comment: They're [not against the rules](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/are-homework-questions-on-or-off-topic), but I refuse to help anyone with their homework while denying it is homework, and without showing any research effort themselves.

Comment: @tfb Would you like me to close this topic?

Comment: @Ineedhelp: that's up to you: if you are using the site to do your homework for you you're not hurting anyone but yourself.